# Eclipse plugin development: unknown extension point

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I want to use the CDT-plugin nature for my project.

```
   <extension
         id="project.mycnature"
         point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature">
      <runtime>
         <run
               class="sp40plugin.nature.ProjectNature">
         </run>
      </runtime>
   </extension>
```

Even thought I added almost every single .jar file of the CDT I can't seem to find this extension point. I am a plugin-coder-beginner.. can somebody tell me how to make this right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add all the plugins as dependencies in the manifest.mf ?

Check this link for CDT downloads http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

cheers,
Saurav